# JSoup handles only a fraction of HTML pages right

Tags: web-crawler, apache-storm, stormcrawler

I hate to monopolise this forum, but at the beginning there are many questions...

Is it normal for JSoup to only handle a fraction (definitely less than 50%) of HTML pages found on the web correctly and discover new urls in them? This is what is happening with my seed file and it is frustrating.

Or are there better parsers out there I could use?

Regards

Comment: It's hard to believe that a mature HTML parser project such as [jsoup](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup) with more than 1,000 commits should perform so bad. Can you share examples and detailed metrics?
However, my guess would be that you want to do the parsing including all page dependencies and modifications of the DOM tree done via JavaScript.  Have a look at SeleniumProtocol. The result may look different compared to that if only the bare HTML page is parsed.

Answer (score 1):

Check the value of *http.content.limit*. It could be that you are getting partial results because the documents are truncated.

EDIT: maybe try the [DebugParseFilter](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/digitalpebble/stormcrawler/parse/filter/DebugParseFilter.java) to see what the DOM generated by JSoup looks like. Like Sebastian suggested, it could be JS related.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. It is currently set to 2 MB, and I have checked that the documents in question are significantly below this limit...

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying that. Where on earth does it put the DOMDump.xml though?

Comment: https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/blob/282b6eda1d2b608c72f26e8de265f94ce5623596/core/src/main/java/com/digitalpebble/stormcrawler/parse/filter/DebugParseFilter.java#L57

in the /tmp directory